# Getting elements of an html file on the web

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a html page ( using whatever is neccery) that will take an elment from a defined html webpage and put it into my page.

For example: 
In the URL www.something.com the html that is found is:
`<p> myName </p>`

I want my page to simply take what is in the p tag and put it on my page.

Is it possible ?

Comment: i guess you are simply meaning to get the contents of a webpage using some serverside language and then extracting the <p> tag to put it on your webpage. is it?

Comment: I am indeed trying to get html from a cross different domain and inject it into my page. Coding-Freak is right as well. Is this posible only by using serverside scripting?

Comment: Beware of [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS) attacks! Moreover, JavaScript usually isn't used as a server-side language. Which web server software is on your server?

Comment: @Marcel, JavaScript certainly is used as a server side language: ASP and Node.js are two examples.

Comment: @Juan: I knew about Node.js, but does ASP support JS?

Comment: @Marcel: <%@LANGUAGE="JavaScript"%> http://aspjavascript.com/default.asp

Comment: <script language='jscript' runat='server'> lets you use jscript in ASP.  When I did a lot of ASP stuff I had a few "array handling" functions written in jscript because VBScript arrays are horrible to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do it client-side because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). It isn't just a security issue, it means browsers just don't allow cross site talking in JS.

Comment: It is possible, but not without both sites working together to share information (such as with window.postMessage)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get the contents of an element and set the contents of another element you can use `innerHTML`.

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('source').innerHTML;
```

Comment: I want do something like this, but instead of the document in the right side of the '=' I would like it to be an url.

Comment: ah yeah you'll have to use something server side for that (php, C#, ruby, python etc), there are security issues with accessing cross origin data through JavaScript (such as with an iframe for ajax). Once you have the contents of the file you can use a regular expression server side to select out the information you're interested in.

Comment: Ok, I understand that there are security issues with this in Java Script. However, I will never use it in a real web page I only need it to check something. Is it possible at all doing this with JavaScript?

Comment: No it's not possible without both sites working together to share information (such as with window.postMessage)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with PHP there is a awsome lib that allow you to get content of a external site an browse the DOM with CSS selector juste like jQuery.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is scrape pages from your own browser, you should just run your script from a bookmarklet, or from the firebug/developer console.